# Casting Large Numbers

Tags: java, casting, numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        double x1 = (int) x;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x1);
    }
}
```

I'm working on a simple bank account program. It's working fine, but when I try to enter a big number and I cast it, my code breaks down. I isolated that one section of the code to see if it was something wrong with my code or whether it was something else... So I wrote this up really quick and found that when I entered a big number like... 10000000000000000000 and it was casted to an integer, 2.147483647E9 was the result. So then I figured it was an issue with casting.

1. Why does this happen?
2. What can I do to prevent it from happening or what else can I do in order to resolve the issue.

Comment: Because an `int` can't have a value greater then 2^31 - 1. Which is 2,147,483,647.

Comment: The largest possible value of an `int` is 2147483647.  If you need numbers larger than that, don't use `int`.  Use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).  And don't scan it as a `double`.  Use `next()` to scan a token as a `String`, and then use that to construct a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected result of downcasting to an `int` a large number that is too large to fit in the valid range of an `int`.  You are getting `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as a `double`.

[Section 5.1.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) states:

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>
>    a. Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are two cases:
>
>    b. If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.
>
>    - Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.
>    - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>    a.  The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest representable value of type int or long.
>
>    b. The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the **largest representable value of type int or long**.

(emphasis mine)

If you need that value preserved, then you can try casting to a `long` or using `BigInteger`.  If this is supposed to represent money, then I would only use `BigDecimal` to avoid floating-point representation and calculation issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by integer overflow. An integer in java can hold 32 bits, and a long can hold 64 bits. You can use Integer.MAX_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE to retrieve the maximum number it can hold. If you exceed this, no exception will be thrown, but the integer will simply 'overflow'.

To work with arbitrary length numbers in Java, you can use BigDecimal or BigInteger. These are standard Java classes that are a pain to work with, but will never overflow. (You could still run out of memory, but that will cause an exception of course.)